# Prepared statement for MySQL so that it would pick a row containing the highest Timestamp for column that would be greater from given parameter?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, prepared-statement

How to write a Java prepared statement for MySQL so that it would pick a row containing the highest Timestamp value from a column that would be greater from given parameter?

I got as far as: 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_col=(SELECT MAX(timestamp_col) FROM table)

But how to convert it to prepared statement?

Comment: If i known where to put it i guess i would have the statement

Comment: You are not making it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's not really a parameter, it's pretty simple:

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement prest;
try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<server>:3306/<db>","<login>","<pass>");
  try{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_col=(SELECT MAX(timestamp_col) FROM table)";
    prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    // prest.setInt(1,12000); // example of using a parameter for prepared statement
    // parameters go in the SQL as ?
    ResultSet rs1 = prest.executeQuery();
  } catch( SQLException s ) { /* etc */ }
```

You don't need a parameter if you're just asking for a MAX(). It's perfectly safe.

Comment: that is the same what i wrote - its not a prepared statement that would pick a row containing the highest Timestamp value from a column that would be greater from given parameter

Comment: The highest value that's greater than a parameter is the highest value period (or none). You mean the lowest value that's greater, or the highest value that's lesser?

Comment: Anyway, the SQL is just "SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp_col=(SELECT MAX(timestamp_col) FROM table WHERE timestamp_col < ?)" or MIN/> respectively.

Comment: true - too many hours of coding i guess one can get dummer because of it

Comment: Don't worry about it, sometimes the best work comes when you feel dumbest. And sometimes you have to restore from backup in the morning. Coding's funny that way. :p